# TextView of dynamic height know how to position TextView under it

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have two `TextView` widgets added to a `RelativeLayout`. The top `TextView` is the title of an article and will have a dynamic height depending on how long the title is. E.g. it could be 3 lines or 1 line. Sitting right below that is the body `TextArea` that has the text for the article.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".com.puc.mobile.news.PUCNewsDetail"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_detail_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/default_background"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_detail_created"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:shadowColor="#000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_detail_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey_font"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingTop="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/news_detail_body"
                android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_font" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**How can I stack them on top of each other so that the body `TextArea` is always positioned perfectly under the title (pushing it down depending on the height) `TextView`, no matter what the height of the title is?**

Comment: is the title would be undernearth the image?

Comment: can you add screen shots ?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Yes, Image, Title, Body text. That is the order. But the image is always a set height, so I hadn't mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the ids to both the TextViews. And use `layout_below` attribute on textarea TextView.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Article Name"
    android:id="@+id/item_title_text" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Area"
    android:id="@+id/item_area_text" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_title_text"/>
```

**EDIT** Your XML should look like this, do not use `margin-top` on `body` textview. Use `android:layout_below` attribute for your need.

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_detail_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey_font"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/news_detail_body"
            android:layout_below="@+id/news_detail_title"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_font" />
```

Check out

[How to use Relative Layout in Android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-relative-layout-in-android/27748),

[Android RelativeLayout Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/relativelayout/android-relativelayout-example/),

[RelativeLayout Example](http://androidexample.com/Relative_Layout_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=73&aaid=97)

[Developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't even realize that option existed. Thank you!